# Pandas series filtering

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have the following series. My goal is to filter keys with arrays whose length is greater than 1

```
item_id
30       [399.0, 385.666666667, 265.0, 387.571428571, 3...
31       [699.0, 434.0, 675.666666667, 689.0, 685.0, 66...
32                    [349.0, 348.838571429, 221.0, 149.0]
33                                          [499.0, 199.0]
35                                          [399.0, 247.0]
45                                                 [299.0]
49                                                 [249.0]
51                                          [249.0, 127.0]
53                                                 [299.0]
59                                                 [249.0]
66                                                 [399.0]
67                                           [149.0, 99.0]
69                                   [200.0, 237.5, 250.0]
70                                                 [349.0]
```

I planed to do it in a same way

```
price_df.where(lambda x : len(x) != 1).dropna()
```

But I get an error

> ValueError: Array conditional must be same shape as self

Any suggestion how to do it in a proper way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with boolean mask created by [`len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html) for count iterables:

```
price_df[price_df.str.len() > 1]
```